# Ramset nail into concrete

Tags: electrical, cement, anchor, fastener

I have a Home Depot ramset device using the yellow bullets and trying to fasten these wire holders into the concrete but it’s just not working, either they don’t go in all the way to hold it or they nail just bends!

Do I need longer nails?[image]

Comment: Have not used them, but imagine your main problem is not holding the ramset hard enough to the cement and it is bouncing.

Comment: Hmmm I was actually thinking maybe I had too much pressure on it

Comment: wrong nails for the job